# Add a json document with mlab (mongodb in heroku)

Tags: json, mongodb, heroku, mlab

I´m trying to add a document to my mongodb with mlab in heroku:

[image: Create document with mlab]

And the message I get is: "JSON Validation Error: We encountered an error while parsing your JSON. Please check your syntax (e.g. ensure you are using double quotes around both your field names and values) and try again."

Why? Thank you!

Comment: If you give the JSON body as a source code I can check it and give you an answer. From general look it looks OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably the single quotes on your comments array.

Try replacing with:

```
"comments": [
  {
    "comment": "This is insane",
    "author": "Matt Daemon"
  }
]
```

Also as @rotemy said, you have any doubts if your JSON is valid, use a validator and you will be able to solve this kind of issues much faster

Comment: Thank you very much! That was the problem!

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't add the source code of your JSON, I would recommend using online JSON checking tool such as [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/).